# Onepage Checkout error - Review is not defined

Tags: checkout, ce-1.9.0.1, onepage-checkout, error

I'm using Magento CE 1.9.0.1 with a custom theme purchased from ThemeForest, and I've enabled the necessary payment methods.

On the onepage checkout, if I click on *Place Order* in the final step (Order Review), nothing appears to happen. When I then checked in Firefox console, I see that the error ***ReferenceError: review is not defined*** shows whenever I click on *Place Order*.

I cannot for the life of me figure this out or troubleshoot what the problem could be. I've tried:

- Copying `/skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js` into my theme's **skin** folder.
- Copying all of the files in `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review` into my theme's **templates** folder

The last point there was kind of redundant as the theme I'm using does not override any of the base onepage templates. I'm certain something is causing the `review` variable to not be defined, but cannot seem to find where this could be occurring.

Has anyone experienced something similar or can share any insight into how I can troubleshoot this? Many thanks!

**EDIT:** Additionally note that I have disabled the other 2 plugins I am using (Geolocation Currency Converter by Webkul, and Gift Voucher by Magestore) just so that I can try to eliminate what the problem could be. After disabling these, I still cannot proceed past checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just to let those who have similar issues know, the problem was with the GeoLocation Currency Converter extension. It did override some files, but more importantly, the `review` variable was not defined in `templates/checkout/onepage/review.phtml`. Uninstalling the extension and restoring some template files did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

made a gist to fix the error in IE11
override template: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review.phtml
with my gist here:
https://gist.github.com/roman204/c5468879074826dc9b1eb20a6bc5fca4